# Generate jLabel code in Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jlabel

Can anyone explain me why my code doesn't seem to work? Result of this code is an empty screen.

Altough my labels array contains all and right labels. I probably miss something but can't find out what.... thanks in advance!

```
 //create the array
private static JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[135];

private  void setup(){

  for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
    int x; 
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int r;
    z++;
      if (z == 16) {
          z=0;
          y += 40;
      }
    x = 40*z+40;

    labels[i] = new JLabel("foo");
    labels[i].setText("test");
    labels[i].setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0)));
    labels[i].setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32));
    labels[i].setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32));
    labels[i].setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32)); 
    labels[i].setLocation(x, y);

    this.add(labels[i]);
    //this.setVisible(true);

  } 
  //this.pack();
  //this.rootPane.add(this);

}
```

Comment: What is `this` in `this.add(labels[i])`?

Comment: public class WinkelScherm extends javax.swing.JFrame{} the class i work in is an jframe class this will refer to the jframe. after the initializecomponent() ill call this funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what layout manager you use for your content pane (which you didn't post).

You add your labels to your `JFrame` like this:

```
this.add(labels[i]);
```

`JFrame.add()` redirects to the `add()` method of the content pane which by default is a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` layout manager. Calling `add()` on this will add the component to the center. Adding another component will replace the previously added component.

So you end up with a `Jrame` which only has 1 `JLabel` added to its center. Since the panel has a layout manager, you should not call `setLocation()` on its children.

You may use a `null` layout (position components absolutely) which you may or may not do corrently as you did not post all your code.

Or use a proper layout manager which allows you to add many components to the `Container` like [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or use `Container`s like [`Box`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html).

Comment: ah, you're right missed the part of adding an grid layout! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://java.about.com/od/creatinguserinterfaces/ss/simplewindow_4.htm) explains how to add JLabels to a JFrame.

The following snippet from the tutorial is where your problem might lie:

> Now that we have created the JLabel, it needs to be added to the JFrame:
>
> `frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`